# Symfony2 - Keep form validation after modifying field in SUBMIT event

Tags: symfony

I need to modify a field in the SUBMIT form event, but when I do any validation rules on the field are lost.

This is all that's happening in the form type (the title field isn't actually being changed I'm just using it as an example):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("title");

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $form->add("title");
    });
}
```

Any validation rules for 'title' are now lost, either annotation rules defined with the entity or using a separate validator class.

Can I do anything to keep the validation or is it intended that validation rules don't get run for fields which are modified in the SUBMIT event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can handle the `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event instead of `FormEvents::SUBMIT` you will keep the validation. You will need to make sure that the listener is on the child form that you want to edit, otherwise you will have an issue with not being able to add a field to a submitted form.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you're not actually modifying a field you're adding a new one with `$form->add('title')` which will replace the existing 'title' field within the form (which is why the validation constraints are disappearing). You might want to look into [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#validation-groups) for the type of functionality you're aiming for unless you want to elaborate on what you're doing within the submit event?

Comment: The reason the field needs to be modified in the submit event is because it gets added initially as an entity field but with choices being empty (for speed of form loading). I then re-add the field in the submit event to add back all possible choices so that the data is accepted.

I've tried changing to use validation groups but with no luck.

Comment: What sort of speed are you talking about - database speed, render speed, selection speed?